# How and when does quantization work in a TFLite Graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a TF model which was trained with quantization, frozen, converted to tflite with TOCO, and now I have the TFLite HTML Graph Model and json.

I can see that, for each of the tensors in my graph, each have quantization attributes (min, max, scale, zero-pt), and I'm trying to determine how each of these attributes applies to each tensor.

For instance, I understand the [representation of quantized data](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/quantization#representation_for_quantized_tensors), and I can understand that taking the quantized weights/biases, multiplying by scale and adding the minimum value returns the original weights/biases (almost).

What I don't understand:

- Why do some tensors have quantization attributes (eg Relu, Sigmoid) but no intrinsic parameters (like weights and biases do)? Is it because they are output tensors and the quantization is applied before the data is input into the next operation?
- At what points (if any) are the quantization applied during the dataflow through the model? For example, say there is an image tensor of floats passed a conv2d operation - where and how are the quantization attributes of weights/bias/relu used to get the output of the conv2d operation?

Essentially, If I parsed the TFLite models data to a numpy array, what are all the things I'd need to know about the flow of the data through the network (with respect to quantization) in order to recreate the model for inference from scratch.

I can't seem to find any documentation regarding this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convolution inner loop does macc of uint8 values. There is also a smaller outer loop for computing the z-offset portions of the macc.  At the end of each kernel convolution you will need to downscale from the int32 accumulator to the 8 bit uint8 range using a downscale multiplier that is input_scale * kernel_scale / output_scale.  Those three scale values were learned during training, and are in the tflite inference file. This paper explains the operations.
http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers/Jacob_Quantization_and_Training_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf

Comment: I can find the `input_scale` and the `kernel_scale` but where in the quantized model I can find `output_scale`?